# Issues with storing array lengths and array inputs from a given file, where the first integer is the first array's length

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I'm having trouble creating a program that reads a file "data.txt" and takes in the first integer of the file as the length of the arrayA and the first integer of the 2nd line in the file as the length of the second arrayB. I'll be sorting these two arrays afterwards but I just need help trying to get the input from the file and store them in the two arrays.

So the file could look like:

```
4 5 8 6 4
3 8 5 4
```

The first character '4' means that the length of `arrayA` is 4 and contains the next 4 following inputs. The 1st character of the second line, '3' means that the length of `arrayB` is 3. . .

```
int main(){
    FILE* fileP;
    int aLngth=0, int bLngth=0;
    int i=0, j=0;

    fileP = fopen("data.txt","r");

    fscanf(fileP, "%i", &aLngth);
    int arrayA[aLngth];

    for(i=0; i<=aLngth; i++){
        if(i==0){continue;}
        fscanf(fileP, "%i", &arrayA[i]);//store length a

        if(i+1>aLngth){
            fscanf(fileP, "%i", &bLngth); //store length b
            for(j=0;j<=blLngth; j++){
                 fscanf(fileP, "%i", &arrayB[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fileP);
}
```

Comment: `i <= aLngth` should be `i < aLngth`. Array indexes go from 0 to length-1.

Comment: Why are you skipping `i==0`?

Comment: I made a typo when retyping the code here. I was having trouble getting it to copy and paste correctly so I just rewrote it. And I see I will adjust that. Thank you

Comment: I'm compiling with the gnu compiler and it keeps saying a fatal error: iostream: no such file or directory

Comment: This is C code, not C++. You should be using `#include <stdio.h>`, not `#include <iostream>`

Comment: There's no question in your question. What problem are you having?

Comment: The question is why it isn't compiling correctly? Where my error is I suppose. I skipped i==0 because the first number at i==0 is the length of the array so I don't want to insert that number into the array.

Comment: You never define `arrayB` so the code won't compile, much less run.  You probably don't want to define `arrayB` inside an `if` block — if you do, all uses of it must also be inside the same `if` block.  This scheme does not extend well to 3 or more lines of data.

Comment: You already read the length of the array earlier, you don't need to skip it in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should have the second loop after the first one, not inside it.

There's no reason to skip `i==0` in the first loop.

You're missing the declaration of `arrayB`.

The `for` loops should use `<` rather than `<=` in the repeat conditions, because the last index of an array is length-1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE* fileP;
    int aLngth=0, int bLngth=0;
    int i=0, j=0;

    fileP = fopen("data.txt","r");

    fscanf(fileP, "%i", &aLngth);
    int arrayA[aLngth];
    for(i=0; i<aLngth; i++){
        fscanf(fileP, "%i", &arrayA[i]);
    }

    fscanf(fileP, "%i", &bLngth);
    int arrayB[bLngth];
    for(j=0;j<bLngth; j++){
        fscanf(fileP, "%i", &arrayB[j]);
    }

    fclose(fileP);
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code but I have received the following error: data.txt:1: error: expected identifier on '(' before numeric constant

Comment: Why are you trying to compile `data.txt`?